# Tomcat 7 - use <jsp-file> in <servlet> in web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat, migration, tomcat7, web.xml

I just switched servers from Tomcat 5.5 to 7 in my eclipse dev environment.
I have a web.xml file which contains the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Calendar</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>
        /budgetCalendar.jsp
    </jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Calendar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Calendar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everything else seems to work normally, but when I visit localhost/Budget/Calendar I get a 404 error. (My servlet context is /Budget) Going to localhost/Budget/budgetCalendar.jsp works fine... just the mapping seems broken. All other mappings (to classes, not JSPs) work as they did before. Am I missing something that happened in Tomcat 7? Can't seem to find any docs about the <jsp-file> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a space in your web.xml.  Did you look at your access.log?
Maybe this would work:
`<jsp-file>/budgetCalendar.jsp</jsp-file>`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in same environment (eclipse + Tomcat 7). Maybe you should check the web.xml schema version? I'm using this :

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
...
</web-app>
```

Comment: Ya, my web.xml already matches that. Unfortunately I gave up and worked around by moving the JSP to a directory called Calendar and renamed it to index.jsp. so I can still use localhost/Budget/Calendar.